# PHP: file_exists() and copy() on paths with whitespace

Tags: php, path, filesystems, escaping

The system I'm operating on is CentOS 6. Suppose I have this filepath: `/var/www/examplesite.com/uploads/Dog Photos/happy dog.jpg`

To support spaces, I'm running a simple `$filepath = str_replace(' ', '\\ ', $filepath)` to escape the whitespace.

This results in a new filepath: `/var/www/examplesite.com/uploads/Dog\ Photos/happy\ dog.jpg`

However, `file_exists($filepath)` returns false.

This is odd because `stat /var/www/examplesite.com/uploads/Dog\ Photos/happy\ dog.jpg` returns the correct information on the file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible fix? http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php#49900 or try it without excaping?

Answer (score 0):

Make folder permission 777 to get all access of that folder. Also on file upload you can change the name of file just inserting underscore instead of space.